# Parse query that perform an in statement?

Tags: parse-platform

How do I do an `in` statement in parse cloud code?

Basically given an array of users I need to create an installation query that includes this list of users, so that I can send them a push.

```
var installationQuery = new Parse.Query("Installation");
// in function doesn't exist, it's just an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve
installationQuery.in("user", usersArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `[PFQuery whereKey:matchesQuery:]` method. Here is an example that finds the users that are near a location, but you can adjust the user query to what you need:

```
// Find users near a given location
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"location"
       nearGeoPoint:stadiumLocation
        withinMiles:@1]

// Find devices associated with these users
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:userQuery];

// Send push notification to query
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
[push setMessage:@"Free hotdogs at the Parse concession stand!"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Edit to add:
The `matchesQuery:` should be more efficient, but if you already have the array of users, you could use this method on PFQuery:

```
- (instancetype)whereKey:(NSString *)key containedIn:(NSArray *)array
```